# Could not find stripe-2.2.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am using Rails 3.2.16 with Ruby 1.9.3. When I added the stripe gem to gemfile and run `bundle install`, version 2.2.0 of stripe was installed.

When I ran `rails s`, I got this error:

```
Could not find stripe-2.2.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

Should I install specific version to 1.9.3 of Ruby version?

Comment: @sawa ran ?? and why minus ??

Answer (score 0):

[Stripe's Ruby gem](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby#stripe-ruby-library-) dropped support for Ruby 1.9 in version [2.0.0](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby/blob/6bd1d6b9a04456ff7c64f76ae7db99d8c1fdf670/History.txt#L121).

If you're still using Ruby 1.9, you can install the last version in the 1.x branch (1.58.0).

Comment: Thank you, whenever i run gem install stripe -v '1.58.0' I got Fetching: stripe-1.58.0.gem (100%)
ERROR:  Error installing stripe:
 mime-types-data requires Ruby version >= 2.0.